# Why does $\left\{ {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} ({x^*}{A^{ - 1}}x):{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1,x \in C}\right\} \subseteq \left[ {0,\infty )} \right.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_n$ is invertible, and

$\left\{ {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} ({x^*}Ax):{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1,x \in \mathbb{C}^n} \right\} \subseteq \left[ {0,\infty )} \right.$

How do I prove that

$\left\{ {{\mathop{\rm Re}\nolimits} ({x^*}{A^{ - 1}}x):{{\left\| x \right\|}_2} = 1,x \in \mathbb{C}^n} \right\} \subseteq \left[ {0,\infty )} \right.$?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not taking $x\in \mathbb C^n$?

Comment: Since $y^*A^*y=\overline{y^*Ay}$ then $Re(y^*A^*y)=Re(y^*Ay)$. Let $x=Ay$ and notice that $x^*A^{-1}x=y^*A^*A^{-1}Ay=y^*A^*y$.

Comment: @Daniel - We know that $x=Ay$ and ${\left\| y \right\|_2} = 1$.Why does ${\left\| x \right\|_2} = 1$?

Comment: Note that the restriction of $\|x\|_2 = 1$ is inconsequential: if 
$$
\{\Re(x^*Ax):\|x\|_2 = 1, x \in \Bbb C^n\} \subset [0,\infty)
$$
then it immediately follows that
$$
\{\Re(x^*Ax): x \in \Bbb C^n\} \subset [0,\infty)
$$